# Disabling the default routing system with Ubiquity-framework

Tags: php, routes, frameworks, url-routing

I'm setting up a small application with [Ubiquity Framework](https://github.com/phpMv/ubiquity) in PHP, and I'm trying to disable the default routing system (`controller/action/parameters`).

The routing system is based on annotations (documented [here](https://micro-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controller/router.html)).

I have a controller with a few routes, which works (don't forget to reset the router cache).

```php
namespace controllers;

class FooController extends ControllerBase 
{
    /**
     * @get("foo")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        echo "I'm on /foo";
    }

    /**
     * @get("bar/{p}")
     */
    public function bar($p='default p')
    {
        echo "I'm on bar/".$p;
    }

}
```

the addresses **/foo**, **/bar** and **/bar/xxx** are accessible, but I would like to disable the default routing system that allows access to the action of an existing controller (without route).

I want to disable the following urls:

- /FooController
- /FooController/index
- /FooController/bar
- /FooController/bar/xxx

I didn't find my answer in the doc.

I know the framework is not known (I discovered it through [phpbenchmarks](http://www.phpbenchmarks.com/en/comparator/framework) website), but the routing system is pretty classic, and it's still php.

If you have any ideas....

Versions:

- php 7.3
- Ubiquity 2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, indirectly in the doc.

The `priority` attribute of a route allows you to assign the order in which it will be defined (and therefore requested).

To disable the call of actions on existing controllers, it is therefore possible to define a generic route in the last position returning a 404 error.

```php
namespace controllers;

use Ubiquity\utils\http\UResponse;

class FooController extends ControllerBase 
{
    ...

    /**
     * @route("{url}","priority"=>-1000)
     */
    public function route404($url)
    {
        UResponse::setResponseCode(404);
        echo "Page {$url} not found!";
    }
}
```

If we still want to activate some controllers (the Admin part for example), we must add the `requirements` attribute, which allows to specify a regex.

```php
namespace controllers;

use Ubiquity\utils\http\UResponse;

class FooController extends ControllerBase 
{
    ...

    /**
     * @route("{url}","priority"=>-1000,"requirements"=>["url"=>"(?!(a|A)dmin).*?"])
     */
    public function route404($url)
    {
        UResponse::setResponseCode(404);
        echo "Page {$url} not found!";
    }
}
```

In this case, the only routes accessible are those defined with annotations + those corresponding to the actions of the `Admin` controller

With routing problems, routing solution.